# Why is beta-reduction called *beta*-reduction?

Tags: math-history, lambda-calculus

In the context of the lambda calculus, why is beta-reduction called "beta-reduction" and not just reduction, or evaluation? Is there a different kind of reduction that it needs to be distinguished from?

Comment: I agree that there is no "deep" meaning in the choice. $\alpha$- and $\beta$-conversions seem to be originated with [H.B.Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry); see Haskell Curry & Robert Feys & William Craig, [Combinatory Logic: Volume I](https://books.google.it/books?id=fEnuAAAAMAAJ) (1958), page 90.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's mnemonic for anything. I think it was just ordering. $\alpha$-conversion is a prior concept to $\beta$-reduction. Next, $\beta$-reduction is the core rule of the lambda calculus. $\eta$-expansion/reduction is an important but less significant transformation (and was likely identified later). There's also $\delta$-reduction which in this case is likely mnemonic for "definitions". The [Calculus of Inductive Constructions](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual006.html#conv-rules) also has $\iota$-reduction for inductive types, and $\zeta$-reduction for `let` expressions. (I have no idea why they chose $\zeta$, though clearly they weren't going to choose $\lambda$.) Other formal systems built on the lambda calculus have no doubt introduced other reductions and used a similar naming scheme (mainly for tradition at this point).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how widespread this is, but in some of the literature $\alpha$- and $\eta$-*conversion* are called $\alpha$- and $\eta$-*reduction*. E.g. see [here](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps112/Spring03/readings/lambdacalculus/reductions.html), or google "alpha reduction" or "eta reduction" for more examples. (Personally, I prefer calling all three reductions, but there might be a good reason for separating them that I'm not seeing.